# Вырезать все что находиться между тегами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть текст, в котором много закоментированного кода, а закоментирован он так:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>тут код<![endif]-->
```

Вопрос. Как убрать(вырезать/заменить) все что находится внутри

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]> вырезать это <![endif]-->
```

Comment: `[if ...]` условия то разные, или всегда одно? и какой смысл оставлять сами комменты тогда, если внутри не будет ничего

Comment: @teran условия всегда одно. желательно и комменты тоже удалять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кто-то подправит в плане эстетичности, но я бы вырезал вот так:

```
$string="<!--[if gte mso 9]> вырезать это <![endif]-->";
$pattern = "#<!--\[(?:.*?)\]>(.*?)<!\[(?:.*?)\]-->#s";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Ответ будет:

```
string(25) " вырезать это "
```

Получается в моем случае не важно какое условие, берёт всё внутри комментария.

Comment: а мне бы не вывести текст который внутри тегов, а удалить его, желательно с тегами этими)

Comment: @Денис так вопрос же был вырезать то что внутри, если удалить, то замените на preg_replace($pattern, '', $string), только ответ не забудьте забрать в котором тегов не будет уже)

Comment: отлично, то что нужно! спасибо за помощь. а еще что, можно ли в шаблон еще добавить чтобы удаляло все в <style>*</style> ?

Comment: @Денис лучше по проще регулярку сделать, типо такой - <style>(.*?)<\/style> и так же потом пройтись по тексту